# Is there a way I can share system resources across a heterogenous system?

Tags: distributed-computing

I have two machines, one is a laptop running windows 7, the other a desktop running fedora.

Is it possible to connect the two computers together somehow so that the laptop uses the memory or disk resources of the desktop or the other way round?

Comment: I can't imagine why you would want to use memory over the network.  A swap file would be faster and even that is not a substitute for provisioning enough ram.

Answer (score 2):

No, not with the HARDWARE you have. Not cost effectively, at least.

Ther are some Hypervisors out there that allow you to combine multiple machines into one - but that is a fringe system and has STEEP hardware requirements.

As in: You need a FAST network between them. FOrget 10gigabit - you talk of multiple 40g Infiniband links.

Given the seriously low end hardware, the costs would make this stupid. YOu are cheaper off just getting a decent machine.

If you want to learn more, check for OpenMOSIX, OpenSSI, Kerrighed. The keyword is "Single System Image".